# How does chrome mobile app parse html?

Tags: android, html, ios, google-chrome

In a chrome browser app for a smartphone, I am wondering how it parses the html code into GUI. Does it turn it into native widgets like buttons, fields, etc... Or is it something else. Because chrome is native app, and if it does convert the html into native widgets, then why does it not feel as smooth as a regular native app? There is all discussions on web app vs native apps, and they all say native apps run smoother, but then what type of widgets does chrome app dynamically create if not native widgets?

Thanks